# Some Good Web Analytics Tools

Tags: google-analytics, web-analytics

I'm looking for a good analytics system which tracks what links a user has clicked on, how long he's stayed on the page, etc.  Does anyone have any recommendations on programs to use?  Not sure if Google Analytics does this

Thanks

Comment: Not programming related, superuser.com or serverfault.com are better places for this king of question.

Answer (score 3):

Google Analytics will do this, you can also setup goals in Google Analytics . Take a look here: http://services.google.com/analytics/tour/index_en-US.html